# Python Sorting a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a list such as the following. I need to sort the lists in order of the second element in each sub-list.

```
chars = [['Andrew', '1'], ['James', '12'], ['Sam', '123'], ['Zane', '2']]
```

I am currently using this command:

```
chars = sorted(chars, key=itemgetter(1))
```

My Ideal output would be:

```
chars = [['Andrew', '1'], ['Zane', '2'], ['James', '12'], ['Sam', '123']]
```

Comment: For completeness, you should post the output you're getting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert second element into integer first for sorting:

```
>>> sorted(chars, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
[['Andrew', '1'], ['Zane', '2'], ['James', '12'], ['Sam', '123']]
```

If you want to do it using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> sorted(chars, key=lambda x: int(itemgetter(1)(x)))
[['Andrew', '1'], ['Zane', '2'], ['James', '12'], ['Sam', '123']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myCmp(x, y):
    if int(x[1])>int(y[1]):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

chars.sort(cmp=myCmp)#chars.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[1]))

print chars
```

output:

```
[['Andrew', '1'], ['Zane', '2'], ['James', '12'], ['Sam', '123']]
```

Maybe can help you.